# what is going on with ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, iptables

I used this command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

because i was trying to stop port 22 outgoing since i was getting a warnings from amazon and now i cant ssh in....what do i do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSH runs on port 22. You've just told your firewall to stop all incoming SSH traffic. (I.E your connection).

If you didnt save this anywhere then iptables will not have this rule on reboot. Unless you have physical access or a console you will probably need to restart

Comment: If a clean shutdown is initiated, and depending on the distribution settings, the iptables rules may be automatically saved on shutdown/reboot.